# Задача для тех кто учиться python

Tags: python

Есть такая задача:
Создайте функцию, которая проверяет чётное число передано в параметре или нет. Она должна возвращать True или False.

Сделал так(по образцу) и  вроде работает но я не понимаю как работает подскажите верно ли сделал и как правильно и почему:

> Создаю функцию которая проверяет на четность

```
def chet(x):
    return x%2==0
```

> Функция которая определяет True или False

```
def number(x,r=True,h=False):
    s=chet(x)
    if s:
        return r
    else:
        print(h)
```

> Вывод

```
print(number(4))
```

Comment: `def number (n): return n%2==0`, `print(number(4))`

Comment: объясните пожалуйста почему так ?

Comment: `%` - это "остаток от деления". Любое ЧЕТНОЕ число дает остаток от деления на два равный 0, любое НЕЧЕТНОЕ - дает остаток 1.  Вот и получается: берем остаток и проверяем, равен ли он нулю. Если равен, функция вернет True, если не равен, вернет False. После этого возвращенное значение компилятор "подставит" вместо вызова функции и получится либо `print(True)` либо `print(False)`. После чего слово True или False напечатается в консоли.

Comment: если ты ставишь в формуле (см свою первую chet) ==, >(=), <(=), != то результатом будет булева - True либо False сразу. делая return == ты возвращаешь из функции уже сразу либо true если остаток 0 либо false если остаток 1.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаёте функцию `chet`, которая выдаёт результат честности (True или False), следовательно вам проще сделать данную функцию базовой и не создавать другие:

```
def number(x):
    return x % 2 == 0 # если число делится без остатка на 2 - то чётное(True), иначе нечетное(False) 

print(number(5)) # False
print(number(4)) # True
```